# Show JS Alert after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, alert, countdown

I am trying to show a JS alert after 5 seconds. Right now I have this code:

```
<script>
function init() {
    var count=5;
    var counter=setInterval(timer,1000);
        function timer(){
            count=count-1;
            if(count==0){
                alert("This is an alert")
                window.location = "http://www.example.com";      
                return;
            } 
        }
    }
    window.onload = init;
</script>
```

The problem is that it's not working right. There is some kind of little error I can't see in the code.

Comment: `var counter=setInterval(timer,5000);` instead of 1000.

Comment: It is working fine, just that you can use `setTimeout()` like  `setTimeout(timer, 1000);` - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xtbfpzb1/2/

Comment: What kind of `little error` ?

Comment: It is working fine. May be you have disabled alerts by clicking 

"Donot allow this page to show more alerts"

Comment: Works. What is the little error?  Also, semi-colon on the alert line.

Comment: Also make sure to stop the interval if you are using `setInterval` once the task is completed.

Comment: @ArunPJohny not seeing the popup on JSFiddle

Comment: @AkshayArora simply it is not working. When I am editing it in Sublime, I don't see the code well colored so I guess there is some kind of sintaxis error.

Comment: @RoyalPinto why is it necessary? how can I do that?

Comment: @Alex sorry.. https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xtbfpzb1/3/

Comment: @Alex If your page gets change then interval will get terminated automatically (which is happening in this case) if not, interval will keep on calling timer function on a specified interval which can impact performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you using setInterval and maintaining a count variable to deduce when five seconds have passed?

Your code could be simplified using setTimeout. For example:

```
window.onload = setTimeout(function(){
    alert('This is an alert');
    window.location = 'http://www.example.com';
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine .Check this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/n08ogzft/)

> Show JS Alert after 5 seconds

where as you are using `setInterval` which mean the `timer` function will execute in every 1 second and it will keep on executing even after alerting.
Check console from developer's tool

Not sure if you need `setInterval` or if you are actually looking for `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

## Try

```js
// ---------------- Try
function init() {
    var count = 5; // set secconds
    var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000 * count);

    function timer() {
        alert("This is an alert")
        window.location = "http://www.example.com";
        //clearInterval(counter) // stop interval
    }

}

window.onload = init;

// --------------- Or

function init() {
    var count = 5; // set secconds
    var counter = setInterval(function() {
        alert("This is an alert")
        window.location = "http://www.example.com";
        //clearInterval(counter) // stop interval
    }, 1000 * count);
}

//window.onload = init;



// --------------- Or

function init() {
    var count = 5; // set secconds
    var counter = setTimeout(function() {
        alert("This is an alert")
        window.location = "http://www.example.com";
    }, 1000 * count);
}

//window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple way is

```
$(document).ready({

setInterval(showAlert(), 5000);
});

function showAlert() {
alert("This is an alert");
window.location = "http://www.example.com";      
return;
enter code here
```

Note: 1 second is equal 1000, so you want this function run after 5 seconds you need set 5000.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. It's just that your `init` function is not being called on window load for some reason. Try directly calling your function or using `document.body.onload` or inserting the script tag at the end of your HTML file, in the body:

```js
//I have a thing of cleaning up code
function init() {
  var count = 5;
  var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
  function timer(){
    count -= 1; //count = count-1 and count -= 1 are the same
    if (count === 0) { //use triple equals sign
      clearInterval(counter); //delete the interval when we are done with it
      alert("This is an alert"); //semi-colon
      window.location = "http://www.example.com";
      return;
    }
  }
}
//Instead of releying on a event, we can just call the function directly
init();
//Or you can check out the HTML for another way
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!--
    All you content will go here.
    And then the script will be placed right after it. It will be ran when the whole document is loaded.
    You can do something like this -->
    <script>/*function init() {...*/</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use `function` inside `setTimeOut`

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  alert("This is an alert")
  window.location = "http://www.example.com";
}, 5000);
```